Banned from the Journal Cureus
Unfortunately, I forgot to correct the ethical approval number of my manuscript and included the approval number of an already published article.
I have been informed that my article has been blocked and my account has been permanently suspended. Later on, I provided them with the correct ethical approval documents and ethical approval number.
Will this unintentional mistake (although I later provided the correct ethical approval number and documents taken from my own institution ) be reported to other Springer journals? Does my account suspension apply to other Springer Journals? Will this affect my whole academic career?

What did folks at the journal say about this when you discussed it with them?

I’m voting to close this question because it's a question for Springer, not for this site.

Well they said tey cannot accept this excuse and they suspended my account forever……

I would apologize and tell them you understand their decision. Mistakes do happen, but with an increasingly fraud-riddled community (or the rise of easier-to-detect fraud) and intensified campaigns to crack down on cavalier attitude towards research fraud, publishers increasingly adopt a zero tolerance policy. Above response will indicate to the editors that you are a professional that accepts the rules of the game, no ifs and buts - and maybe it will mollify them as to not pursue further action if that was on the cards. There are few things that are more convincing than a genuine apology.

Your first question is impossible to answer. If I had to take a guess, I would say that this shouldn't affect other Springer journals. On the surface, Cureus seems to use it's own submission/account system separate from Springer's normal journal system. There probably isn't much intentional communication between those disparate systems so unless an editor went looking, I doubt it would be "reported" per se. This is just speculation though - the only way to know is to ask.
As for how this will affect your career, it probably won't in the long run. (1) Generally, journals don't disclose reasons for rejection. (2) Cureus isn't what most would consider a high-tier journal so you don't lose much by not publishing there. (3) Most venues for exposing research misconduct (which I would argue this is, "mistake" or not) focus on already published research, including Cureus's own "Wall of Shame" (which was discontinued last year anyway).
There are a few caveats though - providing what is essentially a fake IRB/ethics approval is serious. We all make mistakes but you can't make these types of "mistakes" regularly and escape scrutiny for long. Also, while Cureus isn't a high-impact, powerhouse medical journal, it is a convenient place for case reports, smaller studies, and reviews - especially if you qualify for the free publication. So that might be inconvenient for you and could lead to some awkward conversations about why a paper you co-authored can't be sent there.
In any case, I would worry less about how this will impact your career long-term and more about why it happened in the first place and how you can learn from it.

I'm interpreting this question as "I was banned by journal X, am I also banned by all other journals by that journal's publisher?"
The answer is "it depends". Some publishers have mechanisms to block you publisher-wide; others do not; yet others might have it in limited fashion. In the first case the editorial management system flags recognizes you and flags all your submissions; the publisher can then decide (presumably on a case-by-case basis, after reviewing the reasons that got you blacklisted in the first place) whether or not to automatically decline your new submission. For this kind of block you are not "reported" to other journals by that publisher, but the information is there if they search for it.
Other publishers might run different databases for different journals. In that case the new journal might not be aware that you're blacklisted in another journal. It is how, for some publishers, you can tell journal X you will not collaborate with them for publisher-level reasons, and still get an invitation for journal Y by the same publisher.
Sometimes the above is only partial, so it's possible journals X and Y share the same database, but journal Z does not, even though they are by the same publisher. There are reasons for this - e.g. if your name is common, then there should be multiple namesakes around, and any naive blacklist of you might adversely affect others. One way to get past this is to assume that if you currently work in medicine, then you will never publish a math paper, so you are only blacklisted by medicine journals but not math ones.
So the answer is "it depends", and you'll need someone with internal knowledge of Springer to know for sure.
